# Can I copy a file from one server to another?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am using ColdFusion 8.

I am trying to write a file on a networked path Windows.

```
// THIS WORKS
CatalogDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath("E:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\AVCATALOGS\AVCAT\");

// THIS DOES NOT WORK
CatalogDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath("\\ourserver\e$\InetPub\wwwroot\AVCATALOGS\");
```

I can't find any good documentation on what you CAN'T do.

```
// TOO VAGUE
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_36.html
```

Is there a way to write copy a file from one server to another server on networked drives?

Answer (score 4):

you must be running ColdFusion as a network user and that user must have permission to access the server you are connecting to.

Comment: how we run coldfusion as a network in coldfuion 2021